# GTK3 application doesn't show window when run from gdb

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, gtk3, gtkmm

I am trying to debug my GTK3 application with the gdb command, but I can't seem to get it to work. When I run the command `gdb ./myapp`, it loads all the debug symbols successfully. However, when I then call the `run` command in gdb, the app window doesn't open and this is displayed:

```
Starting program: /home/user/build/GTKapp/myapp
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffe3fff6c0 (LWP 146369)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe37fe6c0 (LWP 146370)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdaffd6c0 (LWP 146371)]
[New Thread 0x7fffca3ff6c0 (LWP 146372)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc9bfe6c0 (LWP 146373)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc93fd6c0 (LWP 146374)]
[Thread 0x7fffc93fd6c0 (LWP 146374) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffc93fd6c0 (LWP 146375)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbbfff6c0 (LWP 146376)]
[Thread 0x7fffc93fd6c0 (LWP 146375) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffc93fd6c0 (LWP 146377)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbb7fe6c0 (LWP 146378)]
[Thread 0x7fffc93fd6c0 (LWP 146377) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffbbfff6c0 (LWP 146376) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffbb7fe6c0 (LWP 146378) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffbb7fe6c0 (LWP 146379)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbbfff6c0 (LWP 146380)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc93fd6c0 (LWP 146381)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbaffd6c0 (LWP 146384)]
[New Thread 0x7fffba7fc6c0 (LWP 146385)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb9ffb6c0 (LWP 146386)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb97fa6c0 (LWP 146387)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb8ff96c0 (LWP 146388)]
[Thread 0x7fffba7fc6c0 (LWP 146385) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffbaffd6c0 (LWP 146384) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc93fd6c0 (LWP 146381) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffbbfff6c0 (LWP 146380) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffbb7fe6c0 (LWP 146379) exited]
```

The app window opens fine if I run it without the debugger, and I can run the app beforehand and then attach gdb to it, but it would be nice if I could start the app from inside gdb.

This is the code I use to start the app

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, APPID);
    
    Glib::MainContext::get_default()->push_thread_default();

    System system(argc, argv);
    
    return app->run(system.getWindow() );
}
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal and reproducible example please?

Answer (score 0):

> it would be nice if I could start the app from inside gdb

The *usual* reason an app behaves differently "inside" vs. "outside" of GDB is a difference in the environment -- GDB invokes a new shell, and if your `~/.bashrc` resets the environment, it could be different from "outside" environment and not to application's liking.

You can compare the "inside vs. outside" using:

```
env > /tmp/env-outside
gdb -q -ex 'shell env > /tmp/env-inside' -ex quit
diff /tmp/env-{outside,inside}
```

Alternatively, set a breakpoint on `_exit` and `exit` and use GDB `where` command to see where the application exits. The exit stack may provide some clue as to what's going on.